# A class implementing an interface that takes an enum

Tags: java, generics, interface, enums

So, say I have a simple enum and a class that uses it:

```
enum ThingType { POTATO, BICYCLE };

class Thing {
    public void setValueType(ThingType value) { ... }
    public ThingType getValueType() { ... }
}
```

But, in reality, I have lots of different classes that implement setValueType, each with a different kind of enum. I want to make an interface that these classes can implement that supports setValueType and getValueType using generics:

```
interface ValueTypeable {
    public Enum<?> getValueType(); // This works
    public <T extends Enum<T>> setValueType(T value); // this fails horribly
}
```

I can't change the class model because the classes are auto-generated from an XML schema (JAXB). I feel like I'm not grasping enums and generics combined. The goal here is that I want to be able to allow a user to select from a list of enums (as I already know the type at runtime) and set the value in a particular class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried parameterizing the interface itself.  Like:

```
class Thing<E extends Enum<? extends E>> {
  public E getValueType();
  public void setValueType(E value);
}
```

Then you have the subclass extend the one with right type:

```
class SomeSubClass implements Thing<ThingType> { ... }
```

Comment: There's probably no need to worry about the `Enum` in the bound.

Comment: That definitely works, but the code generator for jaxb interfaces doesn't support genericized interfaces. That might not be so hard to fix, though.

Answer (score 0):

enums are for when you have a fixed set of them. When you say that each implementation has its own, then you no longer have a fixed set, and how you are trying to use enums doesn't match your needs.

You might be interested in the [request for Java to be able to have abstract enums](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6570766).

Comment: Well, each class has one enum that pairs with it - definitely a set of fixed values. What I want is an interface that these enum-holding classes can implement so I can identify them programmatically and call them from the interface. The alternative is testing each individual containing class type, which becomes a maintainability nightmare.